# JPA @Query Bug when using same Parameter for LIKE and =

Tags: sql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I've stumbled upon strange behaviour with a JPA @Query. Using the same parameter for an equals comparison and a LIKE comparison will always pre- and append `%` to the parameter making the equals comparison always fail. Can anyone confirm or even explain this?

Example:

```java
@Query("SELECT * FROM User u WHERE u.name = :term OR u.username LIKE %:term%")
List<Users> getUsers(final String term);
```

The parameter, when calling this with `getUsers("Jonas")` and checking SQL logging, is `%Jonas%`, which means the `= :term` check will always fail.

Does anyone have any insight on this? I haven't found a bug report or any other issue mentioning this as a problem.
Thanks!

Comment: Please open a bug report at https://jira.spring.io/projects/DATAJPA

Comment: I've reported a bug: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-1627
Workaround for now: pass the same parameter twice.

Comment: found an even better workaround: use `CONCAT('%', :term, '%')` to prevent having to send the same param twice